# Display All Authors only

Tags: author

I want to display only Authors not any Subscriber who write blog in my website. So can you help me on this?

```
<?php
            //define vars from user selection
            $howManyAuthors = 10;

            //Get users and count of posts put into array 
            $authorsArray=array();
            $blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
            if ($blogusers) {
              foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
                $post_count = get_usernumposts($bloguser->user_id);
                $authorsArray[$bloguser->user_id]=$post_count;
              }
              arsort($authorsArray); 
              $maxauthor = $howManyAuthors;
              $count=0;
              foreach ($authorsArray as $key => $value) {
              $count++;
                if ($count <= $maxauthor) {
                    $user = get_userdata($key); 
                    $username = $user->user_login;                          
                    $displayname = $user->display_name; 
                    $author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url($key);
                    $post_count = $value;

                      $args=array(
                        'showposts'=>1,
                        'author'=>$user->ID,
                        'caller_get_posts'=>1
                      );
                      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
        ?>
 <?php
                        endwhile;
                     }
                  ?>

                <!-- end of topWriterBox -->
                <?php
            }
          }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Try to properly format your code. Not all loops are closed.

Comment: Please clean up your code, it is unreadable. Use the `{}` in the editor for code

Comment: The code seems to be truncated. Check @WisdmLabs comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to get all users having role Author

```
$args = array(
    'role'         => 'author',
    'number'       => '10',
);

$authors = get_users( $args );
```

For all argument list refer [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)